# Staticfiles for Django cannot be located on IIS 8

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, iis-8, static-files

I have a Django 1.7 website configured on IIS 8 platform. The staticfiles are kept in a folder generated after running collectstatic command. As mentioned in the tutorials I have made that folder a virtual directory and deleted the django handler from it.

Everything worked well till the point I added a new file in my static directory and ran collectstatic again. Now my static files give a 404 error saying **The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

I don't understand why would this happen as I have not changed any of my prior settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My url for the staticfiles was broken. I add the code below to my urlpatterns.

```
url(r'^site_media/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
})
```